# PHP strtotime function give different result on same date on different servers

Tags: php

I am using `strtotime` function with 28th October, 2014 date like `echo strtotime('2014-10-28')` on local and staging servers.

Local server result: 1414468800

Staging server result: 1414425600

Why there is difference between the results on different servers and how can I fix this issue?

Comment: I think its because of the different timezones

Comment: you may try to use [time()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) function.

Answer (score 3):

i think it is because the two servers have diff timezones..

you can atleast do this:

```
 $date = '2014-10-28';  // date
 $timezone = 'America/Virgin'; // timezone you prefer


 $date = new DateTime($date , new DateTimeZone($timezone));

 echo $date->getTimestamp();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the timezone in your `php.ini` file. The value is

`date.timezone = "Americas/New_York"`

I think this values are different on your systems.

Otherwise you have to set it in your scripts but i think its better to set it in your configuration.

Comment: yes , i think so.  you only do this via script if you don't have access on the server configuration.